# Problems implementing a python db listener

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a module for a program that needs to listen for new entries in a db, and execute a function on the event of new rows being posted to this table... aka a trigger.

I have written some code, but it does not work. Here's my logic:
connect to db, query for the newest row, compare that row with variable, if not equal, run function, store newest row to variable, else close. Run every 2 seconds to compare newest row with whatever is stored in the variable/object.

Everything runs fine and pulls the expected results from the db, however I'm getting a 'local variable 'last_sent' referenced before assignment. 
This confuses me for 2 reasons.

1. I thought I set last_sent to 'nothing' as a global variable/object before the functions are called.
2. In order for my comparison logic to work, I can't set last_sent within the sendListener() function before the if/else

Here's the code.

```
from Logger import Logger
from sendSMS import sendSMS
from Needles import dbUser, dbHost, dbPassword, pull_stmt
import pyodbc
import time

#set last_sent to something
last_sent = ''

def sendListener():
    #connect to db
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    #run query to pull newest row
    cursor.execute(pull_stmt)
    results = cursor.fetchone()

    #if query results different from results stored in last_sent, run function. 
    #then set last_sent object to the query results for next comparison.
    if results != last_sent:
        sendSMS()
        last_sent = results
    else:
        cnxn.close()

# a loop to run the check every 2 seconds- as to lessen cpu usage
def sleepLoop():
    while 0 == 0:
        sendListener()
        time.sleep(2.0)

sleepLoop()
```

I'm sure there is a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if results != last_sent:
    sendSMS()
    last_sent = results
else:
    cnxn.close()
```

Python sees that you're assigning to `last_sent`, but it's not marked as global in this function, so it must be local. Yet you're reading it in `results != last_sent` *before its definition*, so you get the error.

To solve this, mark it as global at the beginning of the function:

```
def sendListener():
    global last_sent
    ...
```